# ¿Como usar el polyfill de fetch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, fetch

Tengo una aplicación hecha en **React JS** la cual corre perfecta en todos los navegadores, excepto... si !! excepto en **IE11** al revisar me percate que se debe a la api `fetch()` que no soporta este *browser* dado lo anterior, comence a buscar en internet un *polyfill* que me permita obtener esta funcionalidad en *IE11*.

Termine encontrando varios, pero me llamo la atención este `whatwg-fetch` que es el que más se ocupa e indican en las documentaciones oficiales, lo instale y lo agrege en la parte superior (line first) `introducir el código aquí` de mi archivo donde tengo mi `fetch()`

```
import 'whatwg-fetch'

fetch(...)
```

Cuando lo ejecute con `npm run start` lo probé en *IE11* y no funciono, probe la version compilada para producción corriendo `npm run build` pero tampoco funciono el *polyfill*.

¿Que es lo que estoy haciendo mal al usarlo, o como se usa correctamente? Ya que en la documentación solo indican que se debe usar de esa misma forma.

**RESUELTO 1RA PARTE**

Finalmente pude resolver el problema usando lo siguiente. Siempre importados en la parte superior del archivo donde se va a usar.

```
import 'whatwg-fetch'
import 'promise-polyfill/src/polyfill'
```

**NUEVO PROBLEMA**

Ahora un nuevo problema en el que me enfrento es como decidir en que momento usar el `polyfill` para cuando este navegando en **IE11** que se ejecuten los scripts

Tenia esto...

```
if (!window.fetch) {
    // ejecutar polyfill...
} else {
    // ejecutar fetch...
}
```

Y la condición funciona bien, pero como cargo los `import`acá...

Comment: ¿Qué error te da? ¿Puedes mostrar el código?

Comment: No da ningún error en consola, simplemente carga la pagina en blanco en IE11

Comment: Actualice mi pregunta con la solución y también con una nuevo problema que va de la mano con los polyfill

Answer (score 1):

La documentación de ese polyfill está [aquí](https://github.com/github/fetch) , según dicha documentación, lo que deberías hacer algo como:

```
import {fetch as fetchPolyfill} from 'whatwg-fetch'

fetchPolyfill(...);
```

si lanzas `fetch()` solo va a usar el fetch nativo, que en IE no está implementado.

Comment: Pero de igual forma no funciona y creo saber ya por que, ahora el problema que tengo es como decidir que el código solo se cargue el momento de usar IE11 y no para todos los navegadores...

Comment: Actualice mi pregunta con la solución y también con una nuevo problema que va de la mano con los polyfill

Comment: @vcasas, entiendo que la idea del polyfill es que siempre se use, es decir que  dentro del polyfill debería estar ya solcionado ese tema. Osea que hay dos opciones en mi opinión, o es un bug de whatwg-fetch o IE está utilizando una versión en cache del código, probaste ctrl + F5 ?

Comment: Osea que lo puedo llamar directamente como lo pusiste en la respuesta? `import {fetch as fetchPolyfill} from 'whatwg-fetch'` y usar el `fetch` que debería tener cargado por decirlo así el polyfill junto con el fetch nativo... ¿eso es?

Comment: Claro, así podrías usar ambos fetch.

Comment: Tiene lógica lo que dices, pero en la documentación tampoco indican que realmente funciona así... En el caso que fuese así... el paquete de `polyfill`  `import 'promise-polyfill/src/polyfill'` debería importarse en forma dinámica ya que entenderia que no seria lo mismo que "debería ocurrir" con `whatwg-fetch`